# Get (Identify) Replies to Comments Using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

With the new "Reply" to "Comments" feature on Facebook, I've noticed that replies to comments are treated the same as comments. But I was wondering if there is anyway to distinguish the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can query each `comment` object in the Graph API for the value of its `parent` field. If the comment in question is a reply, then the value of the `parent` field will be a reference to the parent comment. Otherwise, no value is returned.

Reference here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Comment: Seems like Facebook's API has been modified over the past few days, I can no longer get the replies to comments in the same place where I would get the comments to the post. I now have to send a separate request to the /<comment_id>/comments to get the replies. I liked the old way better, if they could just add the parent id right there. But oh well...

Comment: This is ridiculous that i have to query each comment to know whether its reply or not, why can't they just include the "parent" value in the `/comments` api itself ?

Answer (score 12):

You first have to enable `July Breaking Changes` from your app advanced settings

Then use the `fields` parameter with the `comments` graph API and include the `parent.field(id)` column with the and also the `filter` parameter with the `stream` value. *the final result :*

```
{POST_ID}/comments?filter=stream&fields=parent.fields(id),message,from,likes
```

this should return both comments and replies with the `parent` element which has the comment id that the reply belongs to

-- update

and for better array arrangement for replies you can use the following to merge replies with the actual comment array you can include `comments.summary(true)` in the fields parameter

```
{POST_ID}/comments?limit=0&filter=toplevel&fields=comments.summary(true),message,from,likes
```

*filter parameter is optional*

for more info about the fields : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

and in case you want to do it in FQL, check this post's comments http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/new-apis-for-comment-replies/

Comment: The updated version of this works great, although I had to take out 'limit=0'

Answer (score 3):

You can get comment replies in this way.

```
/{{POST_ID}}/?fields=comments{comments}&access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

You can get any sub info(from,id) of comment replies by just nesting fields inside comments like this:

```
/{{POST_ID}}/?fields=comments{comments,from,id}&access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

Similar post over here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743410/6001533

Answer (score 0):

If you're listening for comments on the 'feed' webhook, you should check if:

```
entry[0][changes][0][value][post_id] === entry[0][changes][0][value][parent_id]
```

This will be true for top-level (new) comments, and false for replies to comments.

Answer (score -1):

To piggy back off @sujit's answer I took his answer and in one call from the feed you can get the entire feed, comments and replies to comments as well as associated images to those comments and replies in one shot.

Here is the code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$get_facebook/feed?access_token=$facebook_accesstoken&client_id=$facebook_appid&client_secret=$facebook_appsecret&metadata=1&fields=id,status_type,created_time,from,message,comments{comments{attachment,from,id,message},from,id,message,attachment},picture,link,icon
```