# Facebook Graph API - get comments hierarchy for URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to implement Facebook Comments Widget functionality in my iOS app using Graph API. How to get **ALL** comments in **right** order **without** user authentication and retrieving access_token?

I know, that I can use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=<my-url>
```

to retrieve comments, but this method will return only root (first level) comments. I can add parameter `filter=stream`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=<my-url>&filter=stream
```

and in this case I will receive all comments, but I can't identify which of them are root and parent IDs of nested comments.

Any ideas how to get all comment in right order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found additional parameters, which allows to include `parent_id` in response:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=<my-url>&filter=stream&fields=parent.fields(id),message,from,likes,created_time
```

I hope someone will find it helpful.

Reference: [Get (Identify) Replies to Comments Using the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795133/get-identify-replies-to-comments-using-the-graph-api)